# Horror movie about a virus at the prom; beginning and end are stylized as a cartoon

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Movie seen around 2010, about the virus at the prom, a lot of blood, in some places disgusting, but with humor.

The beginning and end are stylized as a cartoon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Cabin Fever 2: Spring Fever* (2009)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0961722/):

> A high school prom faces a deadly threat: a flesh-eating virus that spreads via a popular brand of bottled water.

The intro starts with live action and becomes cartoonish:

---

Found with the Google query `movie virus prom site:imdb.com/title`.

Comment: And indeed, the ending credits depict the spread of the virus as a cartoon (I've seen the end, but not the beginning, funnily enough).

Comment: @Jenayah Definitely, this is it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ending credits with cartoon at youtu.be/ASDMGqwMvto (NSFW!)